# SQL Join based on code embedded in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use SQL stored in a field to join 2 tables RefTable and DataTable:

This picture is RefTable (DataTable also has LinkFld1 and LinkFld2):

| LinkFld1 | LinkFld2 | OutputFld |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | like %INS% | Alpha |
| 123 | not like %INS% | Beta |
| 234 | like %% | Gamma |

My (non-working) code looks like this:

```
Select D.*, R.Output
from DataTable D 
join RefTable R
     on D.LinkFld1=R.Linkfld1 --Works as intended
     and D.linkfld2 exec(R.Linkfld2) --Doesn't work.
```

Intended Results:

| DataTable.LinkFld1 | DataTable.LinkFld2 | RefTable.OutputFld |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | INS | Alpha |
| 123 | CON | Beta |
| 234 | Anything | Gamma |

How do I rewrite the SQL query to use the text in LinkFld2 as *part of the SQL statement*?

Comment: You will need dynamic sql for that. Its a big-ish topic so I recommend doing some reading and seeing how you get on.

Comment: @DaleK For the courtesy of the visually impaired, I'd also like to avoid embedding tables as pictures. Can you point me to the documentation to correct that?

Comment: lol, thanks. That's fixed now.

Comment: @DaleK I'm picturing an aggravating loop/cursor model that fetches each value to create & execute one statement per line. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to know, there's not quite enough detail to fully answer, but I imagine you can do it in a single query which concatenates all the different components in one go. Given your *JOIN* condition is potentially different for every record, rather than joining them to get the `Output` column, it might be simpler to just use a sub-query (but would need more information to be sure).

Answer (score 3):

Splitting your LinkFld2 into separate pattern and like/not-like indicator fields may get you on the right track. Something like:

```
DECLARE @Map TABLE (
    LinkFld1 VARCHAR(100),
    LinkFld2Not BIT,
    LinkFld2Pattern VARCHAR(100),
    OutputFld VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT @Map
VALUES
    ('123', 0, '%INS%', 'Alpha'),
    ('123', 1, '%INS%', 'Beta'),
    ('234', 0, '%', 'Gamma') -- %% changed to %

DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    LinkFld1 VARCHAR(100),
    LinkFld2 VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT @Data
VALUES
    ('123', 'INS'),
    ('123', 'CON'),
    ('234', 'Anything')

SELECT D.*, M.OutputFld
FROM @Data D
LEFT JOIN @Map M
    ON M.LinkFld1 = D.LinkFld1
    AND (CASE WHEN D.LinkFld2 LIKE LinkFld2Pattern THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = M.LinkFld2Not
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=575cd782419b1c558c38c69ce48214c1)

Comment: Since I wrote the original, I did try this but it ended up making things even more complex. And the entire idea also destroys the basic RDB concept that order doesn't matter.

I fell back on a data table with additional pre-calculated linking fields and reference table that joins to those linking fields. It works just fine but looks clunky.